How do I manage a query where parameters need to change?
How do I update queryParameters such that when I call refetch, the new parameters are used?
Now it seems like it always uses the parameters sent into useGetDataQuery, even if I change queryParameters.
const queryParameters = { id: id, startDate: '2024-05-16', stopDate: '2024-06-15' }
const { refetch, isLoading, isFetching } = useGetDataQuery(queryParameters)

I.e. I want to update startDate and stopDate and refetch with the updated values.
I've tried finding my answer here, but as far as I can tell there's no solution with updated parameters to refetc. React-Query: How to useQuery when button is clicked

React-Query and Redux-Toolkit Query are two separate and completely different libraries, React-Query posts likely won't help you with RTKQ questions/issues. You should just change the query arg value that is passed to the hook, e.g. changing queryParameters to a new value should be sufficient. What exactly is the issue or problem you face though? Please [edit] to provide more complete details about the issue and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant API slice code and the code using the query hook.

@DrewReese Maybe I should've rephrased my question. react-query isn't in use on my end. The query I mention is created by redux toolkit. Anyway. Just making queryParameters into a state variable using useState is all it took as mentioned by Vu Phung.

I will summary your case:

You need change something in queryParameters
After queryParameters change, you need re-call some api.

My idea is using setQueryParameters to change queryParameters by useState and use useQuery to call api when queryParameters has been changed, queryParameters is tracked by useQuery via queryKey.
const [queryParameters, setQueryParameters] = useState({
  id: id,
  startDate: '2024-05-16',
  stopDate: '2024-06-15',
});

const getData = (queryParameters) => {
  // call api
};

const {data, isFetching, isLoading} = useQuery({
  queryKey: [queryParameters],
  queryFn: () => getData(queryParameters),
});

I hope my code can resolve your problem.
